# How can l initialize pointer type struct element

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int n;
    int *m;
}type_tt;

typedef struct{
    struct{
        int x;
        char* y;
        type_tt *h;
    }g;
}mstr;


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int l;
    mstr p;
    p.g.h->m = &l;
    return 0;
}
```

I get a fragmentation fault. This is the statement that seems to cause it: p.g.h->m = &l;. I have tried but can't figure out a way to initialize the pointer m.

Comment: `p.g.h` is an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Have you read the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) yet?

Answer (score 3):

Your `p.g.h` pointer points to Nirvana!

You should define a `type_tt` variable first, then initialize its `m` pointer. And then initialize the `p.g.h` pointer.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    mstr p;
    type_tt t;
    int l = 42;

    t.m = &l;
    p.g.h = &t;

    printf("l = %i\n", *p.g.h->m);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is only partially correct: it doesn't explain things like the scope of variables, and when one would want and use dynamic memory allocation. The user could take this code, use it and end up passing around dangling pointers.

Comment: @NikBougalis I agree that there is a lot that it does not explain. But for the given example it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You get segmentation fault because you forgot to initialize pointer with some new memory or assign existing memory to it before you are dereferencing that pointer.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int l;
    mstr p;
     // initialize with new memory (from heap)
    p.g.h = malloc(sizeof(*p.g.h));
    if(p.g.h == NULL)
        return -1;
    p.g.h->m = &l;
    free(p.g.h);
    // or use existing memory (from stack)
    type_tt t;
    p.g.h = &t;
    p.g.h->m = &l;
    // now you can do something very useful with p.g.h->m
    // print it maybe
    printf("*p.g.h->m is [%d]\n", *p.g.h->m);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Martin R1 said, p.g.h is an uninitialized pointer. You have to allocate memory for it first.

```
p.g.h = malloc( sizeof( type_tt ) );   /// C99
assert( p.g.h != NULL );

p.g.h->m = &l;
```

Do not forget to free the memory once you are done..

Comment: Why `malloc`? Why not just a local variable?

Comment: because the member variable of his struct is a pointer, a local variable would have been more than enough

Comment: So why `malloc`? If a local variable is enough?

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at what's going on here:

You are allocating an int and a structure of type mstr.  The allocation of the int is pretty straight forward, but how about your structure?
When you allocate mstr p, it allocates enough memory for an int and 2 pointers: one pointer to a char and another to a type_tt structure.  It's important to note that you are not allocating the type_tt structure, but rather a pointer to it.  You still need to allocate the memory of sizeof(type_tt) which p.g.h should point to...make sense?

So, something like this:

```
...
int l;
mstr p;
type_tt h;
p.g.h = &h;
p.g.h->m = &l;
...
```

Answer (score -2):

You haven't initialized `p.g.h`.

You can initialize it like:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int l;
    mstr p;
    p.g.h = new type_tt;
    p.g.h->m = &l;
    return 0;
}
```

====

Update:

The default value of pointer is not null, can be any arbitrary value.

If you're in C, you should use `malloc` instead of `new`.

`p.g.h = (type_tt*) malloc(sizeof(type_tt));`

Comment: It is definitely *not* `null` by default. In C, uninitialized local variables can have any value.